# How to unit test cllck event of a hyperlink

Tags: angularjs, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular2-template

```
        I'm trying to add unit tests to my Angular 4 app. In one of my components, there is a link with a (click) handler. When the user clicks the linka function is called which is defined in the .ts class file.

         <a id="lnkOperators_lnk_lbl" href="Operator" (click)="onOperatorLinkClick()">Operator</a>
```

This is  the test case to identify the click event.  Here i have doubt on how to identify anchor tag click event.The highlighted code didnt work  .

```
     it('should', async(() => {
        spyOn(component, 'onOperatorLinkClick');
        **let link = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('a');**
        link.click();

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
          expect(component.onOperatorLinkClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
      }));
```

I tried changing it to button in html and my spec my test case is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests of your Angular application should be done to test your typescript code, I mean, for each isolated function, test that some parameters give some specific result.

What you're doing there is basically testing event binding in Angular what I can assure you that is more than tested. If you want to test something, it should be your own 'onOperatorLinkClick' function. So the test should be something like:

```
it('should', async(() => {
    component.onOperatorLinkClick();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      // Assure whatever your function should do here
    })
  }));
```